# How to cut off / crop bottom AND top of container in React Native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I'm working on a "reels" type application, but I want the user focus to be primarily on the middle horizontal line. Right now, my container is cropping the bottom reel panel partially, which is actually behavior that I would like. However, it leaves the top panel fully intact. How can I ensure that the top and bottom are equally "cut off", leaving only the middle display clear and fully visible?

Here's a link to what it currently looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax2La.jpg. I want the top to be cut off like the bottom is.

Relevant code attached below -- when I shrink the "flex" of the slotsContainer, the bottom shrinks upwards.

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Button, Text} from 'react-native';
import ReelGroup from '../Slots/ReelGroup';

// Implement SPIN Function using ReelGroup Spin within Functional Component
export default function RandomStockScreen(props) {
  const reelGroup = useRef();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>Myster Stock</Text>
      <View style={styles.slotsContainer}>
        <ReelGroup ref={reelGroup} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button title="New Stock" onPress={() => reelGroup.current.spin()} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  titleText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20, 
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: '10%',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  slotsContainer: {
    flex: 0.9,
    marginHorizontal: '3%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 0.1,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    marginTop: '1%',
    marginHorizontal: '3%',
    textAlign: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help you a lot

```
     import React, {useRef} from 'react';
        import {View, StyleSheet, Button, Text, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
        import ReelGroup from '../Slots/ReelGroup';
        
        export default function RandomStockScreen(props) {
          const reelGroup = useRef();
        
          return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text style={styles.titleText}>Myster Stock</Text>
              <View style={styles.slotsContainer}>
                <ReelGroup ref={reelGroup} />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button title="New Stock" onPress={() => reelGroup.current.spin()} />
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        }
        
      const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      titleText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginTop: "10%",
    textAlign: "center",
    borderWidth: 1,
    flex: 0.15,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    backgroundColor: "black",
  },
  slotsContainer: {
    flex: 0.7,
    marginHorizontal: "3%",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    backgroundColor: "grey",
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 0.15,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    marginTop: "1%",
    marginHorizontal: "3%",
    textAlign: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
```

I have some miner changed in container, and button container styles and add one more component name Dimensions.
you can adjust according to your requirement

Comment: It didn't work, the top panel still shows in full while the bottom gets cut off.

Comment: i have been edited the code and change it now it will work for you

Comment: I get the same behavior